# Drawing a table into pdf with pdfbox

Tags: javafx, pdfbox

So my task is to print result of my app (working with JavaFX) into a pdf to save or print them. Right now I try to add a table to the pdf and I looking for a good way (appearance & performance) of doing it. There are two possible way that come into my mind. The first one would be to create a snapshot of the table and add it to the pdf. This looks for me like a simple way, but then I thought this wouldn't work, if the table has so many lines that It would fit on one page (I'm using the A4 format). The other one would be to draw a new table into the pdf. I could add a page break, if the height of the table is at a certain point and continue on the next page. I would be able to work on the appearance and make it look good, but I don't know if this is the best way from the performance perspective. Does someone have any experience in doing that or does someone have another way I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3):

I'm planning on implementing similar feature to my app soon.
Best way to work with PDF files (in my opinion) is *iTextPDF* library.
You can find examples and info how to use the library in https://itextpdf.com .
Quick example (source: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/tables):

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.Color;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.VerticalAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.test.annotations.WrapToTest;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@WrapToTest
public class HelloWorldTable {
    public static final String DEST
        = "results/javaone16/hello_table.pdf";  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new HelloWorldTable().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        try (Document document = new Document(pdf)) {
            Table table = new Table(3);
            Cell cell = new Cell(1, 3)
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .add("Cell with colspan 3");
            table.addCell(cell);
            cell = new Cell(2, 1)
                .add("Cell with rowspan 2")
                .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
            table.addCell(cell);
            table.addCell("Cell 1.1");
            table.addCell(new Cell().add("Cell 1.2"));
            table.addCell(new Cell()
                .add("Cell 2.1")
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
                .setMargin(5));
            table.addCell(new Cell()
                .add("Cell 1.2")
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
                .setPadding(5));
            document.add(table);
        }
    }
}
```

You can add rows automatically by creating a `foreach` loop from your source (TreeTableView, ListView etc), or you can add a *if* loop inside a *for* loop to limit the rows you are adding to the table.
Quick sample code how to do it:

```
//how much free space you have on your pdf page
int rowLimit = 15;
for (int i=0; i<rowLimit; i++){
    //add rows to your table
    //...
    }
```

or you can continue adding new rows in a new page if limit is reached.
Sample code:

```
//how much free space you have on your pdf page
int rowLimit = 15;
int i=0;
//MyDataObject is an Object example where to get data from
//myListOfData is a List where all MyDataObject are stored
for (MyDataObject object : myListOfData){
    if(i==rowLimit){  
        //create new page if limit is reached
        document.newPage();
        i=0; //reset row counter
    }
    i++;
    //add rows to your table
    //...
}
```

> Update: (Ps.: Code Deprecated for  newer versions of PDFBox)

If you want to use *PDFBox* library, you can use this example:
(original/non-edited source code: http://pdfboxtutorial.blogspot.com/2014/08/pdfbox-tutorial-creating-table-in-pdf.html )

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;

/**
 * @author Bharathi Raja
 */
public class CreatePDFBOXTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        createTable();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void createTable() throws Exception {
    String path = "d:\\tablepdf.pdf";  //location to store the pdf file
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
    document.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

    PDRectangle mediabox = page.findMediaBox();
    float margin = 50;
    float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
    float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;
    final float rowHeight = 20f;
    


    //SPECIFY THE NUMBER OF ROWS TO BE CREATED
    //example: use list.size() to get the number of elements
    final int rows = 3;


  
    final float tableWidth = page.findMediaBox().getWidth() - (2 * margin);
   
    //draw the rows
    float nexty = 650;
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 1) {
            contentStream.drawLine(margin, nexty, margin + tableWidth, nexty);
        }
        nexty -= rowHeight;
    }

    contentStream.drawLine(margin, 300, margin + tableWidth, 300);
    int y = 650;
   
    //drawing columns the columns
    float nextx = 50;
   
    int h = 300;
    contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, h);
    nextx = 100;
    contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, h);
    nextx = 350;
    contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, h);
    nextx = 420;
    contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, h);
    nextx = 475;
    contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, h);
    nextx = 545;
    contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, h);

    //now add the text

    contentStream.close();

    document.save(path);
    document.close();
    }
}
```

If you want to use the *foreach* loop to continue writing to next page, you can edit my sample above, replacing:

```
document.newPage();
```

with:

```
//set page format
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
document.addPage(page);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The question was about pdfbox, not about itext.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thnx for pointing it out, I updated my answer!

Comment: This answer works but its outdated, some of used methods are deprecated.